# Flutter how to set an offset, based on screen ratio, without a context?

Tags: flutter, offset

I want to get the `Offset` of the middle of the screen, without using `context`. Is that possible?

Instead of working with pixels, I want to work with screen ratio. For instance, in order to get the center of the screen, I will set the Offset as the following `Offset(0.5, 0.5)`.

Comment: What's the use case? I feel like this is maybe an XY problem. There might be solutions to whatever you like to do that don't involve `Offset`. Like maybe `Align`? I could be wrong though. But it might still be useful to explain what you want to do with it

Comment: I'm building a simple game app, in which the user needs to dodge objects on the screen. I want to verify that the position of creating new objects is not close to the user's current position. I have the user GlobalKey, but I don't have a `context` on creating the new object. Can I maybe get the screen ratio position from the user's global key?

Comment: I have found a possible solution (without using GetX). Since I have the user global key but don't have a `context`, I can retrieve a `context` from the global key: `MediaQuery.of(userKey.currentContext!).size.width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible in base flutter. However the `Get` package allows you to do this and much much more without context https://pub.dev/packages/get .

Comment: Can you please give an example using the `Get` package?